# How to find the smallest subtuples of n m-tuples such that all n subtuples are pairwise different?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I have n m-tuples with elements from $\{0,1,2,3\}$, so $a_{ij} ∈ \{0,1,2,3\}$ for $i∈M = \{1, ..., m\}$ and $j∈N = \{1, ..., n\}$. I would like to determine the smallest subset $M'$ of $M$ so that the corresponding subtuples $a_{i'j}$ with $i' ∈ M'$ and $j ∈ N$ are all pairwise different.

Here is an example in R:

```
> n <- 10
> m <- 20

> set.seed(13)

> set_of_tuples <- replicate(n, sample((0:3), m, replace = TRUE))

> set_of_tuples
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    2    0    2    1    2    2    0    0    1     2
 [2,]    0    2    0    2    1    2    0    0    3     0
 [3,]    1    2    3    3    3    3    2    1    2     1
 [4,]    0    2    2    2    1    2    2    2    3     3
 [5,]    3    0    2    1    2    1    1    1    0     0
 [6,]    0    2    3    1    2    0    0    3    3     3
 [7,]    2    0    0    1    3    1    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    3    1    1    0    1    0    0    2    3     2
 [9,]    3    1    2    1    1    2    3    2    3     0
[10,]    0    2    2    1    3    2    3    2    3     3
[11,]    2    1    2    1    0    1    0    0    1     1
[12,]    3    1    1    1    3    0    3    1    2     1
[13,]    3    3    0    1    0    0    1    3    2     0
[14,]    2    3    3    0    3    1    0    2    1     0
[15,]    2    2    0    1    0    3    3    1    0     2
[16,]    1    0    1    3    1    0    3    1    0     3
[17,]    1    1    0    0    2    3    3    2    3     2
[18,]    2    0    1    1    3    1    2    2    1     2
[19,]    3    3    0    0    3    3    1    2    3     3
[20,]    2    0    0    2    3    3    0    3    1     1
```

Let $s$ be the length of $M'$. Obviously, $s ≥ n^{(1/4)}$ since there are only $4^s$ different subtuples of length $s$. In the examples above $s ≥ 2$.

```
> s <- ceiling(n**(1/4))
```

To test if a suitable subset $M'$ of length $2$ exists you can evaluate all possible subtuples:

```
> pairwise_compare_subtuples <- function(i){
+ combn(ncol(set_of_tuples), 2, FUN = function(j) identical(set_of_tuples[i,][, j[1]], set_of_tuples[i,][, j[2]]))
+ }


> index <- combn(nrow(set_of_tuples), s, FUN = NULL, simplify = FALSE)

> tmp <- lapply(index, pairwise_compare_subtuples)

> table(!unlist(lapply(tmp, any)))

FALSE  TRUE 
  187     3
```

So, in the example here, there are three $2$-element subsets of $M$ for which all $n$ subtuples (i.e. pairs) are pairwise different. From the index you can tell the first one is the pair $(9, 15)$ and indeed for

```
> set_of_tuples[c(9,15),]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    3    1    2    1    1    2    3    2    3     0
[2,]    2    2    0    1    0    3    3    1    0     2
```

the $10$ pairs are all pairwise different.

While in principle this works, it gets very slow for large $n$ and $m$. So I would like to ask two questions.

1) Is there a better approach to this than "trial and error", i.e. evaluating all possible subtuples?

2) If not, can the computation be made faster in R?

Any suggestions welcome and thanks a lot in advance,

mce

Comment: It would improve your Question if there were a definition of *subtuple* near the outset of the body of text.  Since an $m$-tuple implies a fixed size and order of the elements, the notion of subtuple should presumably account for any restriction on size and order.

Comment: Perhaps instead of asking (as in the title) for "the smallest subtuples", your problem would better be stated in terms of smallest index subset $M' \subset M$ needed to differentiate between all the $m$-tuples (that the *restrictions* of the $n$ functions on $M$ to $M'$ are all distinct).